# Statistic Questions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dataset

I just want to know what kind of data analysis I would need for experimental research which involves an independent variable (experimental vs control). I am measuring 2 dependent variable (pain scale and skin reaction) pre, during and post treatment. Convenience sampling used and randomly assigned. I am thinking this would be a MANOVA? What do you think?

Stat Girl

Comment: A useful title will distinguish your question from all, or almost all, other questions on a site.  Could you improve yours?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could analyze such data with a MANOVA. You can use `manova()` in R, which calls aov but has different test statistics invoked when calling `summary.manova()`, and I believe there are also implementations with **PROC GLM** in SAS

EDIT: I guess there are extensions of the MANOVA to repeated measures in the sense of your multiple time points measurements, but it should be noted that doing a univariate repeated measures ANOVA for each response variable independently is also often called a MANOVA